# invoking scheme interpreter on unix

Tags: unix, scheme, mit-scheme

I've just downloaded mit scheme 9.2 on unix.  However, I couldn't do the "make install" step because I'm not a superuser.  So, I added export MITSCHEME_LIBRARY_PATH=\ ~/mit-scheme-plugins:/usr/local/lib/mit-scheme-x86-64 to my bashrc as suggested.  So it should be installed now?

But when I type "scheme" on command line, it says command not found.  How can I invoke scheme or make sure scheme is installed properly?

Comment: You need to add the path where you put Scheme to `PATH`.

Comment: what would the code look like for that?

Comment: It depends on what shell you're using. I bet there's a stack overflow question for that; really, that question is totally independent of scheme.

Comment: You should configure the build to use your own local installation directory (`./configure --prefix=...`) and read an introduction to Unix.